# Can I write value in Div TAG?

Tags: php, mysql, html

Question: Can I write value in div tag?

```
  echo "<div id=\"something_$value\" value=\"$value\"></div>";
```

Comment: I don't know for what reason you want that but `value` is an invalid attribute for a `div` element, and thus your HTML will be invalid, if you want, you can make it a custom attribute like `data-value`, this way, it's completely valid as of HTML5

Answer (score 2):

There is no `value` attribute for the `div` element, so no.

If you want to write content to the div, then it goes between the start tag and the end tag.

If you want to attach arbitrary data to the element (e.g. for processing with JS), then use [a `data-something` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes).

Comment: Example please! My purpose to pass different value for each row displayed from mysql

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the data-field instead.

http://api.jquery.com/data/

(I guess you want to use the data in jQuery or something similiar)

Answer (score 0):

If you have `$comments` array
then try this:

```
foreach($comments as $comment){
    $id = "comment-".$comment['id'];
    echo "<div id=\"$id\" >$comment['comment']</div>";
}
```

this will generate html like this:

```
<div id="comment-1" >this is my comment</div>

<div id="comment-2" >this is my comment2</div>
```

**1st option:**

If you want data inside div try this:

```
echo "<div id=\"something_$value\" >$value</div>";
```

if you have `$value = "value"`;

then generated html will be:

```
<div id="something_value" >value</div>
```

**2nd option:**
you you are wanted to pass value as data attribute:

for unique name in a loop like your id  try Something like this:

```
echo "<div id=\"something_$value\" data-something_".$value."=\"$value\"></div>";
```

it will generate html($value=value) :

```
<div id="something_value" data-something_value="value"></div>
```

see details example and description : http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/customattributes.shtml

I think it makes sense!

Comment: @user3181614: did you try this? you can try any option

Comment: I am trying sir, but little confused. What I want it to work as <input type="text" name="$name" value="$name"/> It it should give value for div tag too?

Comment: I want to pass different div value in javascript/ajax for each row of comment.

Comment: @user3181614 : i have updated my answer can you try this now?